# NodeJS, wait.for module and mysql query

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Trying to use the wait.for module with a mysql query ( can do it with callbacks but would be nice to be able to do it with 'wait.for' )

I know that the sql connection query is non-standard so I'm not sure how to convert it.

```
var getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE id= '5'";
connection.query(getUserQuery, function(err, rows, fields){
     ....
});
```

How would I go about waiting to get the rows of this before my code proceeds on ?

[link to module 'wait.for'](https://www.npmjs.org/package/wait.for)

The part I am not understanding is at the bottom of that page - (Notes on usage on non-standard callbacks. e.g.: connection.query from mysql ).

Comment: Learn how to write proper async code - there is no other way in node.  You can use one of many libraries to help you (promises, async, etc...), but in the end you need to write good, clean, maintainable async code.  It will not help to try avoiding it.

Comment: This is merely a question of how to use a certain module that I would like to try out and see how it works.

Comment: Perhaps if you linked to the module (I can't find it with a search so don't know what it does), you might get more people willing to look into it.

Comment: Ok, I added the link in the post ^

Comment: A bunch of database examples here: http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor#notes-on-usage-on-non-standard-callbacks-eg-connectionquery-from-mysql

#### Notes on usage on non-standard callbacks. e.g.: connection.query from mysql

wait.for expects standardized callbacks. A standardized callback always returns (err,data) in that order.

A solution for the sql.query method and other non-standard callbacks is to create a wrapper function standardizing the callback, e.g.:

```
 connection.prototype.q = function(sql, params, stdCallback){ 
             this.query(sql,params, function(err,rows,columns){ 
                                 return stdCallback(err,{rows:rows,columns:columns}); 
                         });
 }
```

usage:

```
try {
  var getUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE id= ?";
  var result = wait.forMethod(connection, "q", getUserQuery, ['5']); 
  console.log(result.rows);
  console.log(result.columns);
} 
catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
}
```